Are there examples of restored monarchies with discontinued King namings?
I have deleted my previous question. It seemed it has many answers in UK history.
so I am asking a new one. Are there restored monarchies with discontinued king namings?
For example, imagine we have a John II before the abolition and then we have a John I after the restoration (wether the discontinued number is the restorer king or several kings later).

Same issue - because you've asked about plural examples, this is a list question and does not have an Authoritative answer.  Please revise the question so that an arbitrary independent observer can evaluate the optimum answer.

Louis XVI, (Louis XVII was never crowned, outlived his father Louis XVI by one year or two), Louis XVIII was crowned as XVIII after Napoleon abdicated. Napoleon I was emperor, (his son, Napoleon II never reigned), and in 1852, Napoleon III is crowned as emperor.

@MasB While your comment provides good information I meant a decrease or a non-change in the number. For example, imagine we have a John I again after a John I (whether consecutive or not); or a John I after a John II (again consecutive or not).

The papacy has re-used ordinals that were first used by anti-popes but has never restarted numbering. ;John XXIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipope_John_XXIII), who died in 1419 was considered legitimate at first, but was definitely made an antipope by John XXIII's choice of that ordinal in 1958.

England had several King Edwards before starting the numbering back at I, is that the kind of thing you mean? Edward (the Elder) in 899, then Edward (the Martyr) in 975, then Edward (the Confessor) in 1042, before we get to Edward I in 1272 (and up to Edward VIII after him).
